# Loader method of my travel itinerary an infinite number of times

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my Router

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route
      path="/"
      element={<Home />} 
      loader={async () => {
        const s = localStorage.getItem('s');
        console.error(s);
        if (s) {
          return redirect('user');
        }
        return null;
      }}
    >
      <Route path="user" element={<div>1</div>} />
    </Route>
  )
);
```

When `redirect` action are called some infinite loop is happen and my loader method starts called infinite times.
I don’t understand what happens after redirecting to a child route, why does the loader in the parent route start to be called again and how can I solve my problem?

What are the ways to redirect from the parent wave to the child from the loader method?

Comment: Is the closing `Route` element not there ? I see it is only <Route> when it should be `<Route />` (for root path)

Comment: Are you basically trying to implement some sort of route protection scheme? If I had to guess, the redirect should redirect to a route that `"/"` ***doesn't*** handle so you are not render looping. Can you clarify the use case here?

Comment: as you see "/" is root route for my app, but i just want redirect user to child rout if condition is true

Answer (score 0):

````
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route
      path="*"
      element={<Outlet />}
    >
      <Route index path="" element={<Home />}   loader ={ () => {
        const s = localStorage.getItem('s');
        console.error(s);
        if (s){
          return redirect('/user');
        }
        return null;
      }}/>
      <Route path="user" element={<div>1</div>} />
    </Route>
  )
);```

We must create child index route and make redirects from it
````

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you can't "unconditionally" redirect to a nested/descendent route since this necessarily requires the parent route doing the redirect to rerender again, thus triggering the redirect. This is the render looping.

What you can do is to redirect to any non-nested/descendent route, e.g. a sibling route or ancestor route higher up the tree.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route>
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={<Home />}
        loader={async () => {
          const s = localStorage.getItem('s');
          if (s) {
            return redirect("/user");
          }
          return null;
        }}
      />
      <Route path="/user" element={<div>1</div>} />
    </Route>
  )
);
```

[image: Edit loader-method-of-my-travel-itinerary-an-infinite-number-of-times]